# What's this knot called?

Tags: knots, rappelling, knot-identification

I came up with this variation of the flat overhand knot *(also known as the Euro Death Knot)* for pulling ropes on a rappel. I've never been comfortable using the Euro Death Knot (EDK), but it's hard to deny the virtues of the EDK for retrieving ropes. I set out to try and come up with a knot that had less of a tendency to roll than the EDK and eventually came up with this:

[image]

It's a flat overhand with one of the strands tied in a double overhand, which, if anything, makes the knot feel a lot more secure.

What I want to know is if this is an original knot, or if it's already been discovered, has a name, and most importantly: whether or not it's being used for rappels.

I came up with a different knot while experimenting, but found out online that it had already been invented and named "knot number 1452" back in the 1940s. This knot however, I can't find any evidence of it being used before.

Does this knot have a name? Or have I come up with something new?

Comment: Do you have an intermediate picture that better shows how the double overhand was added in?  BTW, congratulations on your invention of the "Canadian Death Knot".

Comment: @requiem More like, "The Canadian *Life* Knot".

Comment: I'm not sure I'd trust a knot that I'd invented...especially not to rappell on. The tendency of the "EDK"(as north americans like to call it) to [slip is very much overstated](http://blog.alpineinstitute.com/2009/03/euro-death-knot.html)

Comment: @Liam Every knot was invented by someone. I trust myself a lot more than most people, and I'd trust my knot a lot more than the EDK.

Comment: *which significantly reduces the knots ability to slip.* The EDK doesn't slip.

Comment: @BenCrowell Forgive me, [it *rolls*](https://youtu.be/H3Cg8homvoU?t=49s), apparently [even more so when wet](https://youtu.be/2dKfls3693c?t=13s).

Comment: @ShemSeger: Your first link shows an offset figure-8, not an offset overhand. Yes, the second one is an offset overhand in a rope that has been soaked in water. Any knot can fail if the rope is made sufficiently slippery. Lab tests have never succeeded in getting an EDK to roll (capsize) under normal conditions: http://user.xmission.com/~tmoyer/testing/EDK.html . Since you presumably haven't done lab tests on your knot when it was wet and subjected to thousands of pounds of tension, I don't know how you can conclude that it is any more secure than an EDK when the rope is slippery.

Comment: BTW, in the first video, where the offset 8 fails, the mode of failure isn't rolling. When a knot fails by rolling, the tails get eaten up. In the video, it's clear that there is still plenty of tail left when the knot fails. The rope broke, probably right below the knot, where you can see the exposed white core immediately before the failure. This should also help to make it clear that the tensions in these experiments are much greater than you could ever get while rappelling.

Comment: Even with the offset figure-8, which has been implicated in several rappelling accidents, you can't get it to roll if it's been carefully dressed and pretensioned. In the lab tests where they made that knot roll, they had to intentionally tie it loosely. In the lab tests where they tried to get the (dry) EDK to roll, they failed even when they intentionally tied it loosely.

Comment: I'm with @Liam - I wouldn't trust a knot I'd invented either.  Not until it had been thoroughly tested anyway.  To some people the offset figure of 8 "feels a lot more secure" than the EDK but it definitely isn't.

Comment: @BenCrowell `"Your first link shows an offset figure-8, not an offset overhand."` I suggest you look again, the first link shows a flat overhand, *then* a flat overhand figure 8. If you watch the video from the beginning they test a multitude of climbing gadgets.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems unlikely it will be useful to other users in the future.

Comment: I know it has been stated, but please don't rappel with a knot that has not been pull-tested. The EDK rolls when subjected to incredibly high forces, and each subsequent roll takes more force. With enough tail a well dressed EDK or "overhand knot" how I call it, is a safe knot for rappelling, with the benefit of having a small profile. It has been extensively pull tested. Learn how to tie it safely and use it.

Answer (score 6):

I think you invented a new knot, or at least one that is decently documented (my non-trivial search came up empty).

Regardless, the bigger question (as others pointed out in the comments) is how it handles in various tests, and whether it fares better, worse, or on par with the flat overhand bend. Even if it was previously named, it may not have been tested in climbing scenarios with climbing loads, leading some to a false assumption that it was safe.

You should contact a rope manufacturer or independent lab to test your knot in various scenarios.

[SARRR](http://sarrr.weebly.com/contact-us.html) has a pull test setup, they might help.

[DMM](http://dmmclimbing.com/about/contact-us/) has a drop test setup, they might help.

Keep us posted!

Answer (score 3):

I've shared this knot with a few members of the Alpine Climbing Club of Canada. The national representative for my section liked it a lot. I told him I was planning on naming it the 'abseil bend', and he disagreed. He's decided that it should be called the *'**Shem-lock**'*. I was reluctant to accept that name, but he insisted. So... it's officially called the Shem-lock now. It's essentially a flat-overhand and a half; a locking knot for the flat-overhand knot, or EDK (Euro Death Knot).

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly sure I have seen this documented by Mark Grommers of PACI.

On this page http://www.paci.com.au/knots.php you can download the document 01_knots.pdf (password is given on the webpage). In v5.3b (16th Oct 2017), on page 37 and 38 there are two variations of the offset overhand bend for joining two rappelling ropes.

The first takes one working end around inside the knot a second time, the second (p38) takes one end a double turn around the lower part of the knot, ending up with a formation that looks very much like what you have 'invented', a combination of a double and single overhand. This variant is specifically highlighted for use in ropes of differening diameters, using the thinner rope to make the double turnand making sure it is underneath the thicker rope.

Mark does a much better job of explaining and illustrating this than I can here. He lays claim to both but acknowledges the idea for the second came from Dan Lehman in 2015. *When* in 2015 is not clear, so maybe you have a claim here, and "Shem Lock" might be the official name in future. Maybe you could get in touch with Mark to discuss shared attribution, linking to this page as proof of date of your discovery.

Comment: Get in contact with the IGKT if you want the name officially recognized.